# MkAnnotationView - show annotation like userlocation animation (blue dot with circular halo )on touch point

Tags: ios7, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am trying to subclass MKAnnotationView to get the animated pin like that shown on the current user location.

I can do that in a sub classed view. Is there any standard way to achieve this?